# Probability (Confidence) Estimates Using Google AutoML Tables

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, multiclass-classification, google-cloud-automl

Google AutoML Tables, when used to produce a classifier with multiple output classes, generates a ***confidence measure*** for each of the classification results that looks like a probability. Can this be treated as a probability? If so, what is the method used to generate this probability? Can 95% confidence intervals be calculated for this probability?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this *confidence measure* output can be treated as a probability - thanks to the last **softmax** layer of the network.

Whether the model has a single-class or multi-class output -as mentioned in your question- the mechanism under-the-hood relies on a function ([sigmoid/logistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) or [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function)) that maps real values scores, from the neural network's last layer, into a normalized probability distribution, with the corresponding statistical properties that allow you to treat the outputs as probabilities.

Please see [here](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/multi-class-neural-networks/softmax) a short and simple explanation of the **softmax** layer from Google training course.

> Recall that logistic regression produces a decimal between 0 and 1.0. For example, a logistic regression output of 0.8 from an email classifier suggests an 80% chance of an email being spam and a 20% chance of it being not spam. Clearly, the sum of the probabilities of an email being either spam or not spam is 1.0.

> Softmax extends this idea into a multi-class world. That is, Softmax assigns decimal probabilities to each class in a multi-class problem. Those decimal probabilities must add up to 1.0. This additional constraint helps training converge more quickly than it otherwise would.